# Java - Load CSV to Complex Nested Map with POJO

Tags: java, csv, collections, pojo

I have CSV file which is in the form as below

```
student, year, subject, score1, score2, score3
Alex, 2010, Math, 23, 56, 43
Alex, 2011, Science, 45, 32, 45
Matt, 2009, Art, 34, 56, 75
Matt, 2010, Math, 43, 54, 54
```

I'm trying to find an optimal solution to read the CSV file and load it to a map for lookup purposes i.e. `Map<String, Map<String, List<SubjectScore>>>`. The first string key is for student, the next string key is for year.

```
class SubjectScore {
  private String subject;
  private int score1;
  private int score2;
  private int score3;
}
```

If there is a better way to store the CSV structure to get SubjectScore based on student and year information, I'll like to know that.

Comment: I‘d recommend to use a dependency like open CSV and then iterate trough the rows and map them. In the best case you write a method ‘transformToMap‘ which takes an Array of Strings (the row) as parameter and outputs your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some constructors to `SubjectStore` and use streams to read the file contents and convert it to your required data structure:

```
public class SubjectScore {
    private final String subject;
    private final int score1;
    private final int score2;
    private final int score3;

    SubjectScore(String subject, int s1, int s2, int s3) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.score1 = s1;
        this.score2 = s2;
        this.score3 = s3;
    }

    SubjectScore(String subject, String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        this(subject, Integer.parseInt(s1), Integer.parseInt(s2), Integer.parseInt(s3));
    }
    // getters/toString
}
```

---

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SubjectScore>>> res = Files.lines(Path.of("data.csv"))
            .skip(1) // skip header line
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s*,\\s*")) // get columns
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], TreeMap::new, // key: student
                Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[1], TreeMap::new, // key: year
                Collectors.mapping(arr -> new SubjectScore(arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]), Collectors.toList())
            )));
```